# Why isn't my UIView de initialized the first time after removing observer, but after that it is?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uiview, firebase-realtime-database

I have a UIView that am adding to a parent ViewController and it has a Firebase observer which I am removing when UIView is being removed from parent controller. But the first time that I remove the UIView , deinit() won't be called, after that though, if I add it again and remove, deinit() is being called each time. I can't figure out why, any idea?

UIView with the observer:

```
class TestView: UIView  { 
 var ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
 var hndlI : FIRDatabaseHandle?

 hndlI = ref.child(node).observe(.childAdded , with: { (snap) in
    ...
 }

 func rmvObsr() { //this method is called in parent controller before removing the UIView to remove the observer
      ref.child(node).removeAllObservers()
    }

   deinit {
       print("de initing ")
   }
}
```

Here's paren UIViewController which adds UIView by tapping on a button:

```
class ParentController: UIViewController {
   weak var tstVw: TestView?

   //adding UIView
   @IBAction func seeSocialMedia(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let view = TestView()
        tstVw = view

        tstVw?.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 60, width: self.view.frame.width-100, height: self.view.frame.height-200)

        self.view.addSubview(tstVw!)
    }


    //removing UIView by tapping elsewhere 
     override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
         tstVw?.rmvObsr() //removing observer
         tstVw?.removeFromSuperview()
         tstVw = nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So when you first  click then this is called `@IBAction func seeSocialMedia(_ sender: UIButton)` on the first click that adds `self.view.addSubview(tstVw!)`

then on second click it removes it(if I am reading the code correctly). That is why it is removed on the second click. I moved

```
let view = TestView()
        tstVw = view

    tstVw?.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 60, width: self.view.frame.width-100, height: self.view.frame.height-200)

    self.view.addSubview(tstVw!)
```

to the `viewDidLoad` now when you click the button it will do as you wanted.

Comment: I think there's a confusion here, the UIView is removed when tapped elsewhere but the button. The problem is that the first time when its removed , it's not released but the second time if I add it and then try to remove it it will be release and deinit() is called. I'm confused why it won't call deinit() the first time

Comment: I have your code in a project. When I run for the first time and click the button, deinit isnt called cause the view wasnt loaded but the second time it is called cause it was loaded. You have to load the view before the button is clicked. I mentioned that I put it in the viewDidLoad and when I clicked it the first time deinit was called.

Comment: hmm, I don't have any problem loading the view upon tapping the button even the first time. I am not sure why you don't get the view loaded but you shouldn't need to put that in viewDidLoad to load the View. Like I said problem is when I tap elsewhere to remove the view (I have the view loaded) but yet I don't get deinit() call